# VirtualBox can't start any VM

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have VirtualBox v.5.0.16 r105871 running on Windows 7 Professional x64. And it can't start any virtual machine (I've tried Win7, WinXP, Ubuntu). I get same errors:

[image: First error]

And then:

[image: Second error]

The only thing I found in Google is about switching Avira Antivirus off. But I don't have it installed. What can solve this problem?

Comment: I assume you tried a reboot? VB services sometimes die or become zombies.

Comment: Has it ever worked? If so, when did it stop working, and did you make any changes to your system?

Comment: @root No, it didn't.

Comment: @Aganju Yeah, you are right

Comment: @michaeluskov - We need more information.  There should be an error log that is generated.  If you supply it be sure its in English.  [You don't seem to have the more recent stable version](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.14/VirtualBox-5.0.14-105127-Win.exe) your build seems higher then the stable build.